# How can I change an image in Bitbucket?

Tags: image, bitbucket

I am a newbie guy, an UX person and I want to change a few things on our website.
When I go to source/assets/img in my bitbucket source, I see a bunch of images that the code is linking. Some of these images I want to change, and I am not sure how to proceed.
When I open these img, and I clcik on edit I get only two options: delete or rename.
How can I just upload a different image OR how can I just add and upload a new image with a different file name?
Do I have to change the Syntax mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What source control are you using? Mercurial or Git?

In both this operation may be viewed as an in-place update of a file, delete the old and rename the new one to the old one's name.

This is not efficient. Do not make a habit of it if you can avoid it, as it is very expensive in terms of space.

In either, so far as I know, not being all that experienced with Mercurial, you replace the old file, add the changes, and then commit. Push the change, and that's that.

Comment: thanks. It is Git. When you say delete the old and rename the new one to the old's name, how do you go about this? This is where I am lost. If I delete this image, then I guess I have to create a new file. But I just don't find where can I upload a file. I mean I see this: Creating assets/img/email/ on branch: master and a window where I can add a text but not an image. there is no uplaod button either... I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Git is a command line tool, as such, it is meant mostly for that environment. Clone the repository, add the new file replacing the old:

`git add file` then
`git commit`

Write the commit message, and you should be good.

You might want to try a git gui, you should look for those, as I can't really recommend any off the top of my head, but ultimately you're going to want to understand git. It's really useful, and it will make it easier for you in the long run.
Try this documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial
Or browse this one: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials